# Почему при клике на button1 возникает такая ошибка:Uncaught ReferenceError: myTouchStartS is not defined ? at HTMLButtonElement.button1.onclick

Tags: javascript

```
let button = document.querySelector('.f');
button.onclick = () => {
   document.querySelector('.block-6').addEventListener('touchstart',myTouchStartS);
   function myTouchStartS(e) {
       document.querySelector('.v').innerHTML += 'touch';//вывод в блок  touch
   };
};

//первая функция работает!! присваивает блоку событие(при клике)
let button1 = document.querySelector('.t');
button1.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.block6').removeEventListener('touchstart',  myTouchStartS);
}
//Когда жму на 2 кнопку выводит эту ошибку:uncaught ReferenceError: 
//myTouchStartS is not defined
//at HTMLButtonElement.button1.onclick
//При клике на button1 нужно сделать так чтобы событие удалялось
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если отформатировать код, то видно, что функция `myTouchStartS` объявлена только в области видимости функции `button.onClick`, а не в глобальной. Соответственно в другой функции она не видна. Попробуйте вынести её в глобальную область

```
function myTouchStartS(e) {
    document.querySelector('.v').innerHTML += 'touch';//вывод в блок  touch
};

let button = document.querySelector('.f');
button.onclick = () => {
   document.querySelector('.block-6').addEventListener('touchstart',myTouchStartS);
};

let button1 = document.querySelector('.t');
button1.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector('.block6').removeEventListener('touchstart',  myTouchStartS);
}
```